# Integer program for minimizing maximum Lateness with precedence constraints

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

In studying for an upcoming exam the following problem came up:

Write an integer program to: minimize the maximum Lateness for the one machine scheduling problem with precedence constraints and processing times of jobs all equal to 1 
i.e. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZRZi.png)

where we use the variable [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i888k.png)

I know this is a variant of the famous NP hard 1|rj|Lmax problem that we solve using branch and bound, but I'm a bit stuck on how to approach this one.

Also excuse any formatting issues, this is my first time actually posting in this great place,so bear with me! Thanks

Comment: Is your time so immensely valuable that you cannot be bothered to type the content of the images you link to?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a variable $z$ to represent the maximum lateness.  The objective is to minimize $z$.  Now you need three sets of linear constraints to enforce:

1. $z \ge t$ if $x_{j,t}=1$.
2. Each job is assigned to exactly one time.
3. Two jobs cannot be scheduled at the same time.